# How to select location for Asp.net Website project?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Creating a new website allows you to choose the path of the website files. However, the project file itself is created under the **Projects** folder. How can I create it somewhere else? I would expect some field for that in the dialog, but can't find it.

(This is *not* a web-**application**.)

Answer (score 0):

At least in VS 2013, there is no project file associated with web sites.  There is only the .SLN file.  The .SLN file is merely a simple container for all of the different websites and projects that you would like opened simultaneously in your Solution Explorer, so the location of the .SLN file on disk is not really important.

Still, if you would like to control its location, you cannot do so through the New Website dialog.  You'll have to manually move the .SLN file after you've already created the website.  And in doing so, you would also have to open up the .SLN in a text editor and manually adjust all the relative paths to point to your website location.